# Pass token in every request after login

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, restangular

I have to pass token in every request sent from application after login.

**Goal : I want to authenticate user in every request** - for authenticate I need token at server side. So I have to send token in each request. Token will generated when user login

Step 1 : user enter detail in login form.

Step 2 : if match pass and username I will get "token value" in response.

```
Restangular.all('checkuser').post($scope.userdata).then(function(response) {
    $scope.token = response.data.token;
});
```

I know that I can pass token by

```
App.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('myBaseUrl');
    RestangularProvider.setFullResponse(true);
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=iso-8859-1'});
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams({token: 'token value'})
    RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
        id: "id"
    });
});
```

But I don't know that how can I set "token value" in config block ?

Comment: Who and when is supposed to set 'token value'?

Comment: I do not get why you want to call set**Default**RequestParams() method with a transient token...

Comment: Do you have any alternate option to do this?

Comment: I mean, I don't get what you mean with "this"... :-) What is your real goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Restangular service to set default headers.

```
Restangular.all('checkuser').post($scope.userdata).then(function(response) {
    $scope.token = response.data.token;

   Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams({token: $scope.token});
});
```

Comment: But I want to do in `.config` block. Because by this way I have to add line in each and every request. Do you have any global solution ?

Comment: @Napster : you don't need to call this line every time when you request. This is same as RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams. We are setting our default headers when user log in instead of doing it in config block.

Comment: Do you mean - "Once user logged in then set default request params which will automatically set for every request" ?

Comment: @Napster Yes, that is exactly what i mean.